# Back button breaks page in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, back-button

I have a cakePHP admin with theme on it.

When I navigate and then press the browser back button in Chrome, the page breaks and looks like that:

[image]

and the first few lines of HTML are as follows:

```
                <header>
                    <section class="container_12">
                            <div class="upper clearfix">
```

There is no HTML defined, no header closing tag, no css defined...

When I hit refresh, the page loads normally:

[image]

And the HTML includes the `<!doctype html>`, the header, all the meta tags and so on.

What is the problem?

```
<!doctype html>

<!--[if IEMobile 7]><html class="no-js iem7 oldie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 7)&!(IEMobile)]><html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 8)&!(IEMobile)]><html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|(gt IEMobile 7)]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>johns | Admin</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=160, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/backend/css/style.css" />     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/backend/css/colors/color4/color.css" />       <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/backend/css/grid.css" />      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/backend/css/fixed.css" />     
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/backend/css/print.css" media="print" />

    <!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/libs/selectivizr-min.js"></script>      <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>  
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/jquery.ui.spinner.js"></script>     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>     <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>     <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/jquery.collapsible.min.js"></script>        <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/jquery.cookie.js"></script>     <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>      <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/autoresize.jquery.min.js"></script>     <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/jquery.autotab-1.1b.js"></script>       <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>        <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/ui.multiselect.js"></script>        <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>     <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>       <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/jquery.jBreadCrumb.1.1.js"></script>        <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>     
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/excanvas.js"></script>      </script><![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/jquery.flot.js"></script>       <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>       <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/jflot.scripts.js"></script>             
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/validation/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>       <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/validation/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/blueimp/tmpl.min.js"></script>     <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/blueimp/load-image.min.js"></script>       <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/blueimp/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>      <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/blueimp/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>        <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/blueimp/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>     <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/blueimp/application.js"></script>      <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/blueimp/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/jquery.wysiwyg.js"></script>        <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/controls/wysiwyg.table.js"></script>        <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/controls/wysiwyg.image.js"></script>        <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/controls/wysiwyg.link.js"></script>     <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/controls/wysiwyg.cssWrap.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/hoverIntent.js"></script>       <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins/superfish.js"></script>     <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/plugins.js"></script>       <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/script.js"></script>        <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/mylibs/helper.js"></script>     
    <!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/backend/js/libs/imgsizer.js"></script>     <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script>
        MBP.scaleFix();
    </script>

    <script>
        var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']]; // Change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID
        (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
    </script>

    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.2/CFInstall.min.js"></script><script>window.attachEvent("onload",function(){CFInstall.check({mode:"overlay"})})</script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body class="clearfix">


                <header class="mobile">
                    <section class="container_12">
                            <div class="upper clearfix">
                                <a href="/backend/" class="logo mt20"><img src="/backend/img/johns_logo.png" title="Dashboard" alt="" /></a>                                    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>                 
                                <div class="r usermenu">
                                    <ul class="sf_menu clearfix">
                                        <li>
                                        <div class="sf-with-ul" style="width:160px;">
```

kjhgfd

  [Log out](/backend/authake/user/logout)

```
                                <nav class="mainnav l">
                                    <ul id="mainnav" class="sf_menu clearfix">
                                        <li><a href="/backend/events"><img src="/backend/img/icons/helloadmin/dashboard.png" alt="Sessions" /><span>Sessions</span></a>                                             <ul>
                                                <li class="last"><a href="/backend/events/add">Add</a></li>
                                                <li class="last"><a href="/backend/events">View</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                    </section>
                </header>



<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    });
</script>

<div id="main" class="container_12 clearfix" role="main">

    <div class="box twothirds">

        <div class="boxheading clearfix"><h3><img src="/backend/img/icons/fatcow-hosting-icons/32x32/page_copy.png" title="Schools" alt="" />Sessions</h3><a class="move"></a></div>

        <section>

            <table class="display" id="tabled">

                <thead>

                    <tr>

                        <th>Name</th>

                        <th>Starts</th>

                        <th>Track</th>

                        <th class="tview" style="padding-left:10px;">View</th>

                        <th class="tedit">Edit</th>

                        <th class="tdelete">Delete</th>

                    </tr>

                </thead>

                <tbody>

                                                <tr>

                            <td><strong>Something</strong>&nbsp;</td>

                            <td style="padding-left:10px;">8:00 am&nbsp;</td>

                            <td style="padding-left:10px;">MC&nbsp;</td>

                            <td style="padding-left:15px;"><a href="/backend/events/view/1"><img src="/backend/authake/img/icons/information.png" title="View" alt="" /></a></td>

                            <td><a href="/backend/events/edit/1"><img src="/backend/authake/img/icons/pencil.png" title="Edit" alt="" /></a></td>

                            <td><a href="/backend/events/delete/1" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');"><img src="/backend/authake/img/icons/cross.png" title="Delete" alt="" /></a></td>

                        </tr>






                </tbody>

            </table>

            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

        </section>

    </div>



    <div class="box onethird menu">

        <div class="boxheading clearfix"><h3><img src="/backend/img/icons/fatcow-hosting-icons/32x32/setting_tools.png" title="Actions" alt="" />Actions</h3><a class="move"></a></div>

        <ul class="clearfix">

            <li class="last"><a href="/backend/events/add"><img src="/backend/img/icons/add.png" title="Add" alt="" />Add</a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>



    <div class="box onethird">

        <div class="boxheading clearfix"><h3><img src="/backend/img/icons/fatcow-hosting-icons/32x32/alarm_bell.png" title="Notifications" alt="" />Notifications</h3><a class="move"></a></div>

        <section class="clearfix">

            <div class="login_notification_container"></div>

            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

        </section>

    </div>

</div>




<footer role="contentinfo" class="clearfix">
    <section class="container_12">
        <div class="lower clearfix">
            <a href="#" id="top" class="top">top</a>
        </div>
        <div class="smallest">
            <div class="l">
                <span class="footer_copyright">&copy; Copyright 2012 johns</span>
            </div>
            <div class="r">
                <span class="footer_copyright">&copy; Copyright 2012 johns</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</footer>

</body>
```

Comment: I have same problem. It seems just the ajax dom loading back, after clicking  on the back button. Check your code, the header is disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Any AJAX happening here? Sounds like something is "capturing" the back button in relation to an AJAX call and then somehow messing it up. What happens if you go back twice?

Comment: If I click twice, the browser goes to the right place, but always stays with no CSS, missing header tags and so on

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're having a problem at your own browser. Can you link us to the website so someone can say if it's working or not? (Probably), it's a problem with your browser's settings. Posting a link would quite help anyway.

Comment: It's all behind passwords, but i can paste the full code, let me do that

Comment: What's behind passwords? Settings or the link?

I repeat, a link would be much helpful if you meant the settings. If you mean the link, then double check your settings.

And sure.. Let's see what's there :|

Comment: No , It shouldn't be. I have a same problem on a  different page too.