# Back button breaks page css in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

Have you ever had a problem with the back button in Google Chrome? In the sense that when you select an item from a drop-down menu (ajax loading) , click something on the page, then click the back button, the browser forgets it's ever had a CSS and goes all 1995.

It looks like it just load the the AJAX DOM, not the whole page. After page refresh everything is fine again. 
It should be a similar problem like
 [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788562/back-button-breaks-page-in-chrome).

Comment: Do you have an example page we can look at?

Comment: Solution is  [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421769/popstate-on-pages-load-in-chrome/7060766#7060766

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Popstate on page's load in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421769/popstate-on-pages-load-in-chrome)